# Has anyone managed to get softKeyboardInputAreaOfInterest working?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm building a mobile application using Flex.

I'm trying to set softKeyboardInputAreaOfInterest on each inputs to include the button underneath. The area of interest is smaller than the remaining screen space left by the soft keyboard, and I've set it on viewActivate, ensuring that the correct dimensions are passed.

However, I'm testing in iOS and it just doesn't seem to be working. The correct dimensions are being traced when I set the rect, but the panning behaviour is incorrect.

I've found one or two unanswered posts on this in other threads too. Surely this property wasn't created and documented, but not actually implemented. It seems to do absolutely nothing.

At this stage, I can't get find a way of guaranteeing that both the input field and the button at the bottom of the form are panned into view.

Please help if you can!

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator or on a device?  You said it didn't work on iOS; does it work for Android?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Just tried it on an Android device, and softKeyboardAreaOfInterest is being ignored - only default behaviour of ensuring TextInput is visible on stage, same as iOS. In fact, the default behaviour is even worse on Android, as the app doesn't pan, it jumps. Not only that, but the TextInput is _only just_ visible without any space below it. In iOS at least it pans to the vertical centre. Testing on the emulator wouldn't be any use as there is no soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug – softKeyboardAreaOfInterest doesn't work on iOS. I was in contact with the Adobe AIR team during the AIR prerelease in July. They confirmed the bug and added a sentence to the online AS3 docs ("This property is not available on iOS").

I just tested it again today with the newest version of AIR (version 3.5.0.600) and it's still not working on iOS, but the online AS3 docs have removed the sentence about softKeyboardAreaOfInterest not working on iOS. I'm guessing this is an oversight.

Update, Nov 19 '12: For AIR 3.5, the removal of "not available on iOS" in the AS3 docs turned out to be an oversight which has been corrected. This property still doesn't work on iOS with AIR 3.5.

Update, Nov 20 '12: And today's word from Adobe is that it's not a bug, softKeyboardAreaOfInterest is just not enabled on iOS.